# TableView with TextView: go to next Textview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I'm trying to create a list app and am using a combination of TableView and TextView. I have a groups and groupsItem array that contains the data. I use these arrays to populate the tableview.

When the user hits "enter", I add to the array and reload the table. It's working well but the problem is that I can't get the textView focus to go to the next textView. The next textView is always 'nil'. I have a feeling it's because I'm trying to do it while the tableView is reloading. Any ideas?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var groups = [String]()

    var groupItems = [[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return groups[section]
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return groups.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groupItems[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandingCell

        cell.textView.delegate = self
        cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.textView?.text = groupItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {

            // On enter add to second last item in array
            groupItems[groupItems.count - 1].insert(textView.text, at: groupItems[groupItems.count - 1].count - 1)

            // Reload the table to reflect the new item
            tableView.reloadData()

            // Try to find next responder
            if let nextField = textView.viewWithTag(textView.tag + 1) as? UITextView {
                nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            } else {
                // Not found, so remove keyboard.
                textView.resignFirstResponder()
            }

            return false
        }
        return true
    }


    @IBAction func AddItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
        groups.append("Cake")
        groupItems.append([""])
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: is it required to reload TableView again ? you can directly save data to array when you press enter to navigate to next textView

Comment: The reload is required. I add it to the array before the reload, but without hte reload, the tableview doesn't reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do two things:

1. Ask the table to scroll so the next row is in view, using `-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]`.
2. Ask the table view to lay itself out using `-[UIView layoutIfNeeded]`. The table view doesn't normally add subviews to itself during `reloadData`, only during layout.